# swift4 : How can I display random cell's value by the notification?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to display randomly all cell's value on the tableView by the notification, based on the repeat cycle determined by a user.
However, now the same value continues to appear on my app.

Maybe the cause that I found is that "func sendLocalPush" is called only once when a user set the repeat cycle. Plus in this case below, "randomItem" is a global and fixed variable. Therefore the same value is continuously assigned at "forKey: " and displayed.

ListViewController

```
import UIKit
var list = ["apple", "banana", "lemon"] 
var randomItem = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(list.count)))
```

LocalPushManagerController

```
func sendLocalPush(in time: TimeInterval){

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: list[randomItem], arguments: nil)

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: time, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Timer", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request) { (error) in
        if error == nil{
            print("schedule push succeed")
        }
    }

}
```

setting vc

```
@IBAction func setButton(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let text = timeField.text else {return}
    guard let time = TimeInterval(text) else {return}
    LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPush(in: time)

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I came up with the idea that I duplicate the array for the notification, and continue the process that the assigned element is removed once the notification is fired and new random value is assigned.
But as above the notification request is called only once so that i have no idea how to implement this idea as well.

Do you have any ideas to solve this matter? Any other idea are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: You are using the same value again and again. Because you are not generating random value at every push thats why the initial random value is used. As its global so its only initialised once. Generate the random item value in the push function every time then you will get different values. hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes I thought so too. However even though I declare the random value in the push function, the function is called only once which means the random is created only once, isn't it? It means the func need to be called every time after the push comes up, in order to create and assign the random value.

Comment: Yes you are right. Whenever you want to send a random item from your list you have to generate the random index. Add this logic to the appropriate place and things will work. Hope it helps

Comment: I have tried to find the right place that is able to repeatedly create the random value but eventually, I couldn't find it. If you could help me to solve it, it would be appreciated.